# Neo4j: Returns unique endNode by multiple paths

Tags: neo4j, distinct

I have the following graph: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=dsxkmb

I´m following Patrick, Lena and Hans. Patrick posted his own Video (Video 2) but Lena and Hans only shared this Video (Video 2).

Now my statement is:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[follows:FOLLOW]->(n:User)-[rel:MY_VIDEO_IS|MY_SHAREVIDEO_IS]->(v:Video)
WHERE u.profilname='Me'
WITH v,n,rel
WITH DISTINCT v,n,rel
RETURN v,n,rel
LIMIT 10
```

this statement returns 4 results. 3 times "Video 2" and 1 time "Video 1". But I want "Video 2" and "Video 1" only 1 time returned.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the result based on the person you follow (`n` here):

```
MATCH (u:User{profilname:'Me'})-[follows:FOLLOW]->(n:User)
    -[rel:MY_VIDEO_IS|MY_SHAREVIDEO_IS]->(v:Video)
RETURN v.videoname, collect(n.profilname), collect(type(rel)), count(*)
```